# Tracking data on each request in Yii2

Tags: yii2

What will the best place in the code to track user's last visit date or any data that should be tracked on each request to application? Is it good idea to extend yii\web\Controller?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a base controller and of course it is a good idea. But there is another approach that is more elegant. You can do like below:

**1** - Add a component into your components directory, for example(`MyTrackingClass`):

```
namespace app\components;
class MyTrackingClass extends \yii\base\Component{
    public function init() {
        //SOME CODE HERE
        //SOME CODE HERE
        //SOME CODE HERE
        parent::init();
    }
}
```

**2** - Add `MyTrackingClass` component into your components array in config file:

```
'components' => [
    'MyTrackingClass'=>[
        'class'=>'app\components\MyTrackingClass'
     ],
     //other components
```

**3** - Add `MyTrackingClass` into `bootstarp` array in config file:

```
'bootstrap' => ['log','MyTrackingClass'],
```

Now, you can see everything you wrote in your `init()` method, will be executed in every request, in every `module`, `controller`, `action` and so on...

**Please note that, if you do not need to use `Events` and `Behaviors` you can use `\yii\base\Object` instead of `\yii\base\Component`**